# Do not want to delimit a value in awk

Tags: unix, awk

I have a record like this

```
1664|41.0000|0.683333|0.6560|
```

Command

> $ awk -F"|" '/AL_ALL_CALLS_1.6P/ { if($22>0 && $182!="" && !$183)
>   print $3,$7,$10,$12,$15,$22,$24,$36,$39,$40,$96,$103,$182,$184,$186}'
>   CDR_File_1.txt | awk -F"|" '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if ($i=="") {
>   $i="0" } } OFS=" ";print }' | awk -F" " '{print
>   $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$6/60,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15}' | sed "s/
>   /|/g" | awk -F"[|.]" '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ($i==$i+0)
>   {n=split($i,a,"."); $i=sprintf("%d %d", a[1], a[2])}}}1' | head -1

Output

```
1664 0 41 0 0 0 0 0 683333 0 0 0 6560
```

Expected

```
1664 41 0000 0 683333 0 6560
```

Comment: Just replace the dots with a space --> `awk '{gsub(/\./," ")}1' file`.

Comment: Why `45 0 0` instead of `45 00`. I don't see the logic behind that

Comment: Still wrong output      45 00 0 25 abc anurag jain
25 12 1 25 xyz stack

Comment: I dont want anurg jain i want anurag.jain

Comment: @hek2mgl I guess this is because the first 0 comes from `45.00` and the second one from `0.25`.

Answer (score 1):

Just check if a given field is a number and, in such case, split it:

```
awk '/anu/ {                                  # lines containing "anu"
     for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {                    # loop through the fields
         if ($i==$i+0) {                      # if it is a number
             n=split($i,a,".")                # slice the number
             $i=sprintf("%d %d", a[1], a[2])  # put it back together with a space
         }
     }
}1' file                                      # print the line
```

See it in action:

```
$ awk '/anu/ {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ($i==$i+0) {n=split($i,a,"."); $i=sprintf("%d %d", a[1], a[2])}}}1' file
45 0 0 25 abc anurag.jain
25.12 1.25 xyz stack
```

The key point here is the usage of the [format-control letter `%d`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Control-Letters) in `printf` to remove the now superfluous leading zeroes:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {printf "%d %d", 0000001, 01}'
1 1
```

Also, the usage of `$var == $var +0` to check if a field is a number or not:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {print "a" == "a" + 0}'
0
$ awk 'BEGIN {print 23.0 == 23.0 + 0}'
1
```

---

From your updated question I see you don't need to remove extra zeros: with `$i=sprintf("%s %s", a[1], a[2])` we have more than enough. Also, since you have integers that do not need extra processing, it is best to check for these fields differently, for example with `$i~/^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/`.

```
$ awk -F"|" '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ($i~/^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/) {n=split($i,a,"."); $i=sprintf("%s %s", a[1], a[2])}}}1' file
1664 41 0000 0 683333 0 6560
```

Comment: @Anurag yep, just did it!

Comment: i have a record like this  
1664|41.0000|0.683333|0.6560|

Command